# Textareafield not changing in with when set

Tags: javascript, extjs

why would this be?
there is no resize either and no change in the width?

```
{
    xtype: 'textareafield',
    fieldLabel: 'Notes',
    name: 'notes',
    height: 100,
    width: 150,
    cls: 'resize-horizontal'
}
```

any advice please?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config to make textareas resizable is `resizable`. Just set it to true.

```
{
    xtype: 'textareafield',
    fieldLabel: 'Notes',
    name: 'notes',
    height: 100,
    width: 150,
    cls: 'resize-horizontal',
    resizable: true
}
```

Is the class `resize-horizontal` a custom class of yours ?

Comment: thank you but what about the width? if i want to set it and not make it resizable?

Comment: I don't understand. In the question you ask why you cannot resize, and now you say you don't want it to be resizable.

Comment: i am just playing around with the code, trying to learn how things work  trying out resize and when i only set the width. :)

Comment: thanks the resize is working. something is preventing me from setting the resize or the width, as soosn as i try and resize it when resize is set, the window immediately returns to original size :) i will have to ask fellow collegue about that :)